# Hook a function without a dll

Tags: c, kernel, hook, detours

So I am on a windows computer and it is pretty simple to hook a function using a standard .dll.

My question is tho, I am pretty sure it is possible to hook a function from a kernel mode driver, I was wondering if someone could please point me in the right direction. This may not be possible however after a few hours of searching I found nothing. Probably using wrong key words tho.

Thanks